# Enviar a destinatarios en variables con PHPMAILER

Tags: php, variables, phpmailer

Tengo una variable con x cantidad de correo electrónico, en el ejemplo que usaré solo 2, el problema que tengo es que cuando quiero ingresar la variable dentro de los destinatarios recibo un error, es como si PHPMAILER no reconociera la variable en ese sección.

Este es mi codigo

```
$cadena="'firbedatomasf@gmail.com'";
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';


// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('hostEXAMPLE', 587))
->setUsername('EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.com')
->setPassword('PASS');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('msm'))
->setFrom(['excample@example.com' => 'John Doe'])

->setTo([$cadena => 'A name'])

->setBody('INTENTO')
;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

La variable en sí es $ cadena, luego cuando la ingreso en la línea:
     -> setTo ([$cadena => 'A name'])
no me envies los emails
¿Podría decirme dónde me equivoco o mostrarme cómo hacerlo para poder tomar la variable?

Answer (score 0):

creo que quitando las comillas simples te funcionara bien, tu asignacion es:

```
$cadena="'firbedatomasf@gmail.com'";
```

la correcta seria:

```
$cadena="firbedatomasf@gmail.com";
```

Las keys de un array no necesitan comillas simples para saber que son literales.

Un saludo.

Comment: cuando lo hago asi con UN solo email funciona, pero para hacerlos con mas de uno tengo que separar con comas y comillas simples, asi: 
$cadena="'firbedatomasf@gmail.com', 'firbedatomas@icloud.com'";
 y ahi no me toma la cadena

Comment: Si lo haces con mas, deberias poner " $cadena=["my@mail.com"=>"Nombre","otromy@mail.com"=>"Otro Nombre"];foreach($cadena as $k=>$v)$message->setTo($k,$v);" el "foreach" despues de definir message y define message sin el setTo, prueba tambien a poner "->setTo($cadena)", pruebalo y comenta

Comment: gracias pero no funciona, dentro de cada ->setTo() no acepta variables ni getters

Comment: Perdon fallo mio, segun pones en tu ejemplo al SetTo le pasas un array, define  $cadena como : $cadena=['mymail@mail.com'=>'email1','mymail2@mail.com'=>'email2','mymailN@email.com'=>'emailN']   y modifica ->SetTo($cadena)  asi si deberia de funcionar